# Cyclone DDS Package configuration file missing

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-plugin, data-distribution-service

I'm a beginner looking for some clarity on how to create and run Example for Cyclone DDS

I had build cyclone dds with visual studio 2019, after build i was trying to build and run the basic helloword example

im getting following error when i try to do so. Im pretty much new to Cmake and stuff, can any one help in resolving this error ?

```
rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~
$ cd cyclonedds

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds (master)
$ cd examples

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds/examples (master)
$ cd helloworld

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds/examples/helloworld (master)
$ cd build

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds/examples/helloworld/build (master)
$ cmake ../
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCycloneDDS.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "CycloneDDS", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CycloneDDS" with
  any of the following names:

    CycloneDDSConfig.cmake
    cyclonedds-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CycloneDDS" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CycloneDDS_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "CycloneDDS" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/rkpsr/cyclonedds/examples/helloworld/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds/examples/helloworld/build (master)
$
```

Comment: "I had build cyclone dds with visual studio 2019" - You need not only to *build* Cyclone DDS, but you need to **install** it too. This is stated in the [README](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/blob/master/README.md#for-application-developers). If you specified non-default `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` parameter, then you need to pass the same value as `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` parameter when you build the examples. This is noted in the error message you get.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I had used "cmake --build . --target install" cmd so it will build and install

Comment: OK, so what is about setting of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` parameter(variable), as I described in my previous comment?

Comment: @Tsyvarev it was default

Comment: Do you have the file `CycloneDDSConfig.cmake` under your CycloneDDS installation? What is exact path to that file?